# Sitecore 10.1 xConnect collection database multi-region scaling read-only performance

Tags: xdb, xconnect, sql-database, performance, setup

I have a multi-region Sitecore deployment with CDs in the US and the UK using Sitecore 8.2 with MongoDb as the xDb, like this:

```
UK                                US

CD1                               CD2
Mongo primary + arbiter  <----->  Mongo secondary
```

Mongo is geo-distributed with a connection string on each CD that prefers reads from the nearest replica but will always write to the primary replica. This ensures any kind of read of xDB contact information on page-load is as fast as possible for each region.

I want to upgrade to Sitecore 10.1. MongoDB has been discontinued for xDB (now xConnect) in 10.1 and I must use SQL server.

I have read up on read scale-out (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/xconnect-scalable-reads.html) but this does not appear to be relevant to my use case - it's for same-region scale-out, not for geo-replication.

The official docs (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/scaling-and-configuring-the-xconnect-collection-service-role.html) state that:

> Deploy the xConnect Collection service as close as possible to the xDB Collection database. It is more important to reduce latency between the service and the database than between the service and clients such as Content Delivery.

They also state:

> All instances must read from a single centrally located xDB Collection database (database sharding by geography is not supported).

The docs **don't** state what kind of performance hit you're going to take by the CD communicating to the xConnect service sat in a separate region.

Am I right in thinking that there will be a performance hit due to the db not being geo-replicated? Or is there some other mechanism I'm missing that allows Sitecore to load a contact profile for personalization on page-load? If not, how can I geographically replicate the xConnect collection SQL database in order to minimize read latency on page load within each region?

**EDIT**
I'm specifically talking about the following sequence of events (particularly points 2 and 4) as described in the docs here (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/sitecore-experience-platform/en/tracking-contacts.html)

> 1. Contact visits [www.sitecore.net](http://www.sitecore.net) - they have the
>    SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE set to
>    60573a38-6925-4d92-8bff-327e41650d8f
> 2. **Request is sent to xConnect for the device profile matching
>    60573a38-6925-4d92-8bff-327e41650d8f**
> 3. The LastKnownContactId of the device profile is used to retrieve a
>    contact from xConnect by its tracker identifier
> 4. **If the contact exists, it is loaded into session - if not, a new
>    GUID is generated (the new contact will be saved on session end)**
> 5. At the end of the session, a second interaction is saved against the
>    contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a reverse proxy in the following architecture (apologies for poor Visio skills):

[image]

The key things to note here are as follows...

### Database setup

- The xConnect database is actually 3+ databases: a ShardMapManager plus 2 (or more) shard databases. The default is 2.
- The ShardMapManager db contains the table `[__ShardManagement].[ShardsGlobal]` where the actual server name of the shards is stored. You can edit the `Server` column manually to point to the right server (Sitecore does this for you when you set up xConnect using the `Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe` but it's easy to change).
- I deployed the ShardMapManager db in my main region (UK) and then copied it to my secondary region (US) manually. Note, it is NOT geo-replicated.
- On the secondary US ShardMapManager db I updated the `[__ShardManagement].[ShardsGlobal].[Server]` column to reflect the US server name.
- I then simply geo-replicated the 2 shard dbs into the same US server.

### xConnect setup

- I deployed 2 instances of xConnect, 1 in each region pointing to their respective ShardMapManager dbs.
- The US xConnect instance cannot function fully - it will throw errors if it tries to perform any write operation to the shard dbs, since the shards are geo-replicated read-only replicas.
- The UK xConnect instance is fully functional with read/write access to the shard dbs.
- I pointed my UK CDs directly at the UK r/w xConnect instance.
- I deployed a reverse proxy in the US region which routes to either the UK xConnect instance if the HTTP method = `POST`, or the US xConnect instance if the HTTP method = `GET`. **This is the most crucial piece of the puzzle, and prevents any read-only-based errors occurring on the US xConnect instance**
- The reverse proxy is an nginx web server running on Linux on a VM. I tried to achieve the same with a PaaS solution using Azure Application Gateway but you cannot route based on HTTP Method which was frustrating. The nginx config I'm using is below.
- I pointed my US CDs at the nginx reverse proxy.

### TLS/SSL Considerations

- xConnect requires client certificates for communication between itself and the CDs.
- The introduction of nginx complicates this, because nginx must use the same client certificate as the CDs to communicate with both xConnect instances.
- I attempted to get nginx to forward the client certificate from the CD to xConnect but I couldn't get it to work.
- I solved the problem by installing the client certificate on the nginx VM, and using it in my config as you'll see below.
- nginx must also have its own server certificate just like xConnect does. Since my nginx VM has no public IP or fqdn, and I didn't want to faff around with private DNS zones, I generated a self-signed certificate where the `CN` was just the hostname of the VM. Of course this is not trusted by the US CD, so Sitecore throws SSL errors when communicating with xConnect. To get around this, I installed the self-signed nginx cert into the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" on each US CD VM.

Here is the nginx config:

```nginx
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/{self-signed server cert}.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/{self-signed server cert}.key;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;

        server_name {vm hostname};

        location / {
                if ($request_method != 'GET'){
                        proxy_pass https://{UK read-write xConnect}.azurewebsites.net;
                }

                        proxy_pass https://{US read-only xConnect}.azurewebsites.net;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/{xConnect client cert}.crt;
                        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/{xConnect client cert}.key;
                        proxy_connect_timeout       300;
                        proxy_send_timeout          300;
                        proxy_read_timeout          300;
                        send_timeout                300;

        }
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            server_name  {vm hostname};
            return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The performance hit isn't in the documentation because it depends on a myriad of factors. The key thing to understand here is latency. There are various ways of mitigating this latency however. You can have xConnect Collection role services in each region and use [xConnect Scalable Reads](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/xconnect-scalable-reads.html) combining them with [Azure SQL Auto Failover Group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-overview) capabilities.

I will warn you however that the biggest impact does not come from your xConnect Collection, but from xConnect Reference Data. Even if you choose to have only 1 region with the xConnect databases and Collection service I highly recommend you replicate the xConnect Reference Data service to each regional data center. This service makes heavy use of caching so it will speed up access without needing DB replication and additionally when this service is unavailable your CD will also fail to serve requests.

**How does this work?**

When you activate Scalable Reads under the hood the SQLProvider of xConnect will start adding ApplicationIntent to the connectionstring it receives from the SMM database:
[image: xConnect Scalable Reads]

So what does this mean when combining with Azure Auto Failover Groups? Consider the following:
[image: Azure Auto Failover Groups]

Your failover group has both a Read-write listener and a Read-only listener that will automatically direct your requests along the most optimal and desired path. Thanks to the included ApplicationIntent added by scalable reads you don't need to do anything, Azure and Sitecore are doing everything under the hood for you.

**How to set this up?**

Make sure that inside the SMM database your connection strings are targeting your failover groups.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please expand a bit on why xdb reference data will have a bigger impact? I don't see why that would affect page load speed. The collection database contains the contacts, so it's the latency from CD to the collection db that will impact the load time the first time a user loads a page, right?

Re: using scalable reads with sql auto failover - can you also expand on that please? I'm not sure I follow how to set that up so that a US collection role reads from a US db and a UK collection role reads from a UK db, but both of them write to the UK.

Comment: @theyetiman the fact that the Reference Data Service being down is enough for your CD to stop serving requests should indicate already what type of impact it can have. If you use any of the marketing functionality in Sitecore this service will come under significant usage. It also supports GeoIpData for example. So while Collection will be called 1 time at start and 1 time at end (which is even async so user won't notice) the Reference part can be used on every single page request.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. However, I'm not talking about service outage, rather the realtime page-load latency impact. E.g if it's 200ms round trip from CD to ref data svc  will that add 200ms to every page-load or is there caching of ref data?

I get that the collection svc is only called once in realtime at the start of the session, but that's every single visitor's first experience of landing on my site. First impressions count - it should be fast to load. Today I have UK and US markets to serve, but soon I will add Australia. The latency from Aus to UK is significant.

Comment: @theyetiman In regard to Scalable Reads and Auto Failover Groups I don't want to copy all documentation I referred to you. The walkthrough is here: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--configuring-xconnect-scalable-reads.html to set this up from xConnect standpoint. It does use the read-scale out which is 1 region, multiple availability zones so if you want to go to Failover Groups you will need to do some manual configuration inside the ShardMap Manager database which should NOT be replicated and you need a plan to support failover

Comment: @theyetiman the RefData Service has excellent caching but only in that particular role afaik meaning you are correct about a potential 200ms roundtrip for each call unless you have the service locally in each region. The RefData => DB might still be 200ms (unless you have those scalable reads setup) but thanks to the cache in the service the CD => RefData will almost never take that hit and pages are delayed minimally instead.

Comment: Thanks for ref data svc info. I'll be sure to host the svc/app itself in both regions for low-latency cache access.

Comment: Re: the docs you linked and don't want to copy. Sorry - this doesn't answer my question. I cannot see how to configure an xConnect svc in the US to read from a replica in the US and write to the primary in the UK. I see there's a setting to enable read scale out on the svc - but what is this even doing under the hood? The docs don't say. You say "you will need to do some manual configuration inside the ShardMap Manager database" - please can you explain what that configuration would be?

Comment: @theyetiman That's because you will need to do some modification to enable it, it doesn't come out of the box so it's not documented. To understand what it's doing under the hood when you activate the configuration in xConnect the SQLProvider will automatically add an ApplicationIntent to the connectionstring received from the SMM db causing automatic distribution of read and write operations according to your setup failover group. I'll add some info to my response

Comment: Thanks for your additional detail it's really useful and appreciated. It is my understanding that if I connect to the primary listener with `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` then I will still end up on the primary (UK) server. I've tested this and it seems to be the case. The only way to connect to the secondary server is to use the secondary listener, which is a different hostname. The docs cover it here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-overview?tabs=azure-powershell#using-read-only-listener-for-read-only-workload (see the callout box)

Comment: This means that xConnect would need to modify the hostname in the connection string to add xxx.secondary.xxx to the hostname, instead of just appending ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly. I presume it does not do this? I do not think it would be possible to put a mix of primary and secondary listeners into the SMM database, since the SMM must cater to a connection from any client and it's the app itself that decides to use read-only or not?

Comment: I think it could work if the data was sharded by location somehow - then you could ensure shard0 is UK and shard1 is US, and hard-code the connectionstrings as such in the SMM. You wouldn't even need a failover group or read scale out for this. However I doubt it's possible. I'm now thinking of a different approach involving using an application gateway in front of the US xConnect svc to route read-write traffic (identified by REST url pattern) to the UK xConnect svc and read-only traffic to the US xConnect svc which reads from secondary failover listener and would fail if it did a write op.

Comment: not to detract from this comprehensive response, but you should consider whether all this extra cost and complexity is worth it for the incremental performance improvement. Before embarking on this path you ought to benchmark inter-continental XConnect request performance and compare it with intra-continental performance; you might find that the latency is a small player compared to the performance of the service itself, so all this extra effort will only save you 10s of ms in a 300ms request anyway

Comment: @RichardHauer that's a really good point and definitely playing into my decision making. If it proves too complex or cost prohibitive then I may just have to eat the ~110ms extra on each session start (I benched it between 2 vms in peered vnets in my UK & US Azure regions) but it would be a shame to degrade *any* kind of performance when I'm upgrading Sitecore.

Answer (score -1):

From understanding above you might need to think in Azure Apps way rather than Sitecore.

As all the xDB/xConnect logical role are web apps incase of performance and distributed multi region/ Geo distributed application/environments can be setup by

[App-service-environment-geo-distributed-scale](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-geo-distributed-scale)

And for deployment you might can use [this](https://medium.com/@ajith.ramawickrama/deploying-multi-region-high-available-web-application-in-azure-with-app-services-sql-database-393bb2559f12)

Comment: I understand how to geo-scale individual app services, VMs, dbs, etc. But I need to understand how to scale the xConnect collection service & database from a practical, usable point of view. Obviously I could just create a bunch of sql dbs and geo-replicate them but that won't work because I need a way to allow the xConnect service to know which db instance to read from and which instance to write to. This answer does not help solve that problem, sorry.